# Combination of PanelMenuModule with ng-template or ng-container

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm writing an angular6 project with primeng.

I need to combine the panelMenu tag of primeng with ng-templates. Below are the snapshots for the panel menu.

Without expanding the panel menu.

[image: Panel menu without expansion]

With expanding the panel menu.
[image: Panel menu with expansion]

My panel has 3 headings 
 1. Student
 2. Department
 3. Help 
and each of them contains the submenu's. When ever I click on the submenu's respective ng-templates has to be loaded beside of Menu(in the black space).

This can be achieved by using routerLink option of MenuItem and making each submenu as a separate component. But I don't want to do in that way.
I want to load the respective ng-templates whenever clicked on the submenus.

Please suggest a way, or suggest some sample examples.

Below are the code snippets.

### Component Class

```
export class ViewOrderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  private viewDisplayItems: MenuItem[];
  isStudent: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    this.viewDisplayItems = [
      {
        label: 'student', items: [
          { label: 'addStudent' }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'department',
        items: [
          { label: 'addDepartment' },
          { label: 'deleteDepartment' }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'help',
        items: [
          { label: 'searchStudent' },
          { label: 'searchDepartment' }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

### HTML Template

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="viewDisplayItems" [style]="{'width':'200px'}">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isStudent; then studentMenu; else departmentMenu">
    </ng-container>
</p-panelMenu>

<ng-template #studentMenu>
    <h2>Welcome to Student Menu</h2>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #departmentMenu>
    <h2>Welcome to Department Menu</h2>
</ng-template>
```

isStudent is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu It looks like there isn't a template option like other PrimeNg modules.

However, another option will be to add another item to the items. Use the documentation on the `MenuItem` http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel

At this point you can target the item with CSS to style it with a more desirable look.

```
this.viewDisplayItems = [
      {
        label: 'student', 
        items: [
          { label: 'Welcome to the Student Menu', separator: true },
          { label: 'addStudent' }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'department',
        items: [
          { label: 'Welcome to the Department Menu', separator: true },
          { label: 'addDepartment' },
          { label: 'deleteDepartment' }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'help',
        items: [
          { label: 'Welcome to the Help Menu', separator: true },
          { label: 'searchStudent' },
          { label: 'searchDepartment' }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D on the templates and panelMenu of prime-ng, I came up with below solution.

We can use **command** option of **MenuItem** from primeng to pass some clickable events and handling the dynamic loading of templates.

The codes of component class and UI template are modified as below to work.

### Component Class

```
export class ViewOrderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  private viewDisplayItems: MenuItem[];
  displayPageName: string;
  studentSubPageName: string;
  deptSubPageName: string;
  helpSubPageName: string;

  constructor() {
    this.viewDisplayItems = [
      {
        label: 'student', command: (onclick) => this.displayPageName = 'studentPage', 
        items: [
          { label: 'addStudent', command: (onclick) => this.studentSubPageName = 'addStudentPage' }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'department', command: (onclick) => this.displayPageName = 'departmentPage',
        items: [
          { label: 'addDepartment', command: (onclick) => this.deptSubPageName = 'addDepartmentPage'},
          { label: 'deleteDepartment', command: (onclick) => this.deptSubPageName = 'deleteDepartmentPage' }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'help', (onclick) => this.displayPageName = 'helpPage',
        items: [
          { label: 'searchStudent', command: (onclick) => this.helpSubPageName = 'searchStudentPage' },
          { label: 'searchDepartment', command: (onclick) => this.helpSubPageName = 'searchDepartmentPage' }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

### HTML Template

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel-div">
        <p-panelMenu [model]="viewDisplayItems">
        </p-panelMenu>
    </div>

    <div class="template-div">
        <ng-container *ngIf="displayPageName === 'studentPage'; then displayStudentPage; else checkDisplay1">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #checkDisplay1>
            <ng-container *ngIf="displayPageName === 'departmentPage'; then displayDepartmentPage; else checkDisplay2"/>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #checkDisplay2>
            <ng-container *ngIf="displayPageName === 'helpPage'; then displayHelpPage; else displayStudentPage"/>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #displayStudentPage>
            //code for Displaying students

            //As we have subdivisions in student, those are included as shown below
            // we have only one subdivision addStudent, So both in if and else we included the same template name
            <ng-container *ngIf="studentSubPageName === 'addStudentPage'; then addStudentPage; else addStudentPage">
            </ng-container>

            <ng-template #addStudentPage>
                //code for add Student
            </ng-template>

        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #displayDepartmentPage>
            //code for Displaying Departments

            //As we have subdivisions in department, those are included as shown below
            <ng-container *ngIf="deptSubPageName === 'addDepartmentPage'; then addDeptPage; else deleteDeptPage">
            </ng-container>

            <ng-template #addDepartmentPage>
                //code for add Departments
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template #deleteDeptPage>
                //code for deleting Departments
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #displayHelpPage>
            //code for help Page

            //As we have subdivisions in help, those are included as shown below
            <ng-container *ngIf="helpSubPageName === 'searchStudentPage'; then studentSearchPage; else deptSearchPage">
            </ng-container>

            <ng-template #studentSearchPage>
                //code for searching Students
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template #deptSearchPage>
                //code for searching Departments
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone finds a better solution and shares here will be appreciable.

Thanks.